# Insert Alert inside a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function that I call when I click on a button.
In this function I insert a component to show an alert (*react-native-scl-alert*)

The call enters in the function (the console log is printed) but the alert doesn't work, do you know why? There is something that I do wrong?

Thank you

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state = {
//Alert
  show: false
};


alertFeedback() {
    this.setState({ show: true })
    console.log("Inside Alert Feedback")
    if (this.props.Roles == "ROLE") {

        <SCLAlert
          theme="info"
          show={this.state.show}
          title="Lorem"
          subtitle="Lorem ipsum dolor"
          onRequestClose={()=>{}}
        >
          <SCLAlertButton theme="info" onPress={this.stopConnection} >Done1</SCLAlertButton>
          <SCLAlertButton theme="success" onPress={this.stopConnection}>Done2</SCLAlertButton>
          <SCLAlertButton theme="danger" onPress={this.stopConnection}>Done3</SCLAlertButton>
        </SCLAlert>


    } else {
      this.stopConnection();
    }
  }

  stopConnection() {
    this.setState({ show: false })


render() {
    return (
<View style={activity.button}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.alertFeedback()}
            >
              <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Comment: I don't know how it works in native, but in react-dom you'd usually have the `SCLAlert` shown in the main render method, and just toggle the state to hide/show it. You don't seem to be doing anything with it inside of your `alertFeedback` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code you have to write inside render function of your component always, and for conditional alert the value i.e. `this.state.show` should be true when you want to show it.

render should look like this,

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={activity.button}>
                <SCLAlert
                    theme="info"
                    show={this.state.show}
                    title="Lorem"
                    subtitle="Lorem ipsum dolor"
                    onRequestClose={() => { }}
                >
                    <SCLAlertButton theme="info" onPress={this.stopConnection} >Done1</SCLAlertButton>
                    <SCLAlertButton theme="success" onPress={this.stopConnection}>Done2</SCLAlertButton>
                    <SCLAlertButton theme="danger" onPress={this.stopConnection}>Done3</SCLAlertButton>
                </SCLAlert>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
                    onPress={() => this.alertFeedback()}
                >
                    <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

So, when

```
if (this.props.Roles == "ROLE") {
    this.setState({show:true})
}
```

and don't forget to initialize show in your constructor inside your class,

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            show: false,
    };
}
```

I hope this helps ......Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for reply :) I need to show this kind of alert only if the user  has this.props.Roles == "ROLE"

Comment: yeah just edit your code just like above and it will work ....Thanks :)...Accept it if it works as well @Jack23

Comment: Sorry I don't have understand I should insert <SCLAlert... inside the render?

Comment: Sorry I have a little problem, do you know how can I consider which button was clicked?

Comment: Done1, Done2, Done3 in theory, depending on the button I clicked, I must register a value for a variable.

Comment: onPress={()=>{this.stopConnection(1)}} // when calling from "info"
onPress={()=>{this.stopConnection(2)}} // when calling from "success"
onPress={()=>{this.stopConnection(3)}} // when calling from "danger"

and on stopConnection funtion you can have a conditional statement for the three  conditions
Hope this helps....Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As Per your code you are not rendering the alert you should add some key check and show alert on basis of that  something Like:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //Alert
     show: false,
     showAlert:false
    };


  alertFeedback() {
    this.setState({ show: true })
    console.log("Inside Alert Feedback")
    if (this.props.Roles == "ROLE") {

    this.setState({ showAlert: true})


    } else {
      this.stopConnection();
    }
  }

  stopConnection() {
    this.setState({ show: false })


   render() {
    return (
    <View style={activity.button}>
    <div>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.alertFeedback()}
            >
              <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

     {this.state.showAlert
      ?  <SCLAlert
          theme="info"
          show={this.state.show}
          title="Lorem"
          subtitle="Lorem ipsum dolor"
          onRequestClose={()=>{}}
        >
          <SCLAlertButton theme="info" onPress={this.stopConnection} 
         >Done1</SCLAlertButton>
          <SCLAlertButton theme="success" onPress= 
         {this.stopConnection}>Done2</SCLAlertButton>
          <SCLAlertButton theme="danger" onPress= 
           {this.stopConnection}>Done3</SCLAlertButton>
        </SCLAlert> 
     :""
</div>

)}
```

Hope this will work!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the SCAlert dialogue box becuase you are not writing it in the render() method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state = {
//Alert
  show: false
};


alertFeedback() {
    this.setState({ show: true })
    console.log("Inside Alert Feedback")
    if (this.props.Roles == "ROLE") {
      return (
        <SCLAlert
          theme="info"
          show={this.state.show}
          title="Lorem"
          subtitle="Lorem ipsum dolor"
          onRequestClose={()=>{}}
        >
          <SCLAlertButton theme="info" onPress={this.stopConnection} >Done1</SCLAlertButton>
          <SCLAlertButton theme="success" onPress={this.stopConnection}>Done2</SCLAlertButton>
          <SCLAlertButton theme="danger" onPress={this.stopConnection}>Done3</SCLAlertButton>
        </SCLAlert>
     )

    } else {
      this.stopConnection();
    }
  }

  stopConnection() {
    this.setState({ show: false })


render() {
    return (
<View style={activity.button}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.alertFeedback()}
            >
              <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Stop</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```